# Is there a way of returning a user control object parent that opens a child window?

Tags: window.open

I have multiple controls that I'm using on a page, which contains 3 buttons internal to the control.  One of the buttons launches another dialog window, which when finished closes and returns a value.  The value is being returned properly, the issue is that the parent to the child is always the last control added to the page.  Is there a way of specifying which control is the true parent to the child window?

```
function Button1Click(){
    window.open('<%=DialogLocationHref %>');
}
function Button1Returned(retValue){
    document.getElementById('<%=txtValue1.ClientID%>').value = retValue;
}
```

parent window excerpt

```
...
if (window.parent.Button1Returned != null){
    window.parent.Button1Returned('+ someValue + ');
}
```

Comment: If it helps, when doing a post back to the server, I do see the ID of the object that I want to modify, I can pass that back to the parent page, however I can't get this to work with javascript. Is there something I should be able to set on the object that is retained in some way so that I can work with this using javascript?